# Authenticated User Access Permission for Bing Ads Api

Tags: authentication, user-permissions, bing-ads-api

Is there any way to retrieve the **permissions** of the currently authenticated user (access_token) as they relate to the specified **bing ads** account.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [GetUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/customer-management-service/getuser?view=bingads-12) operation with UserId set to nil. This will return the role for the customer and accounts that the current authenticated user (per the provided access token) can access.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where will I get developer token?